# Upgrading from Ubuntu 19.04 (EOL) to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I tried upgrading but getting this issue. I have updated source.list file as well to old-releases.ubuntu.com.Following is the issue:

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,349 kB]
Fetched 1,350 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade

An upgrade from 'disco' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260939/cannot-upgrade-from-disco-19-04-to-focal-20-04-after-end-of-life-using-do-releas)?

Comment: Thanks this helped me !!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is simply that you are trying to skip past intermediate versions, which the `do-release-upgrade` tooling does not support.

Non-LTS versions upgrade to the next version.

LTS versions upgrade to the next LTS version (unless specifically configured to upgrade to a non-LTS version).

As 19.04 is a non-LTS version the immediate upgrade step is 19.10, then the next step would be 20.04.

The configuration for what type of version to upgrade to is in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`, but keep in mind that it essentially decides where to go next when you currently are at an LTS version, there are really no alternatives when at a non-LTS version.